# Problem with reading lines from a file and storing them into a struct

Tags: c

This is the function I use for reading the data in the files

```
void Core_football_players_recovery(){
     assert(configuration.football_player_counter!=0 && "No se ha cargado de forma correcta el archivo de configuracion");
    FILE *players_file;
    players_file=fopen("data/Futbolistas.txt", "r");
    jugadores = malloc(sizeof(football_player)*configuration.football_player_counter);
    for (int i = 0; i < configuration.football_player_counter; ++i) {
        //Se hace a lo bruto ya que siempre sera asignado igual
        fscanf(players_file,"%s",jugadores[i].id);
        //comprobar que coincide con id equipos
        fscanf(players_file,"%s",jugadores[i].id_team);
        fscanf(players_file,"%s",jugadores[i].nombre);
        fscanf(players_file,"%s",jugadores[i].id_plantilla);
        fscanf(players_file,"%d",&jugadores[i].precio);
        fscanf(players_file,"%d",&jugadores[i].valoracion);
        //Comprobar que coincide con plantillas existentes
    }
    fclose(players_file);
}
```

I am stuck because it stores more characters in the first and the second variables, when i check theese ones I get this output:

```
0102Messi ==> When the output should be 01
02Messi   ==> When the output should be 01
```

Here are the struct used previusly

```
typedef struct{
char id[2];
char id_team[2];
char nombre[20];//maximo de 20
int precio;
int valoracion; //default 
char id_plantilla[3];// se asigna 000 de predetermindo
```

}football_player;

And the content of the file I am reading:

```
01
02
Messi
001
10
9
```

PD: configuration.football_player_counter is readed correctly and located in another file.

Thx in advance =)

Comment: A two character string requires an array of three chars to store. One extra for the terminating NUL character.

Comment: You can either use strings or not use strings, but you have to be consistent. Some of your code is using strings (for example, passing `%s` to `fscanf` is for strings). But some of your code is not (for example, allocating only two bytes for the `id` even though a string has a terminating nul byte). If you want to read precisely two characters, not a string, you can.

Comment: Why use `fscanf()` where `fgets()` is ideal ? `fgets()` reads lines , and lines only. `fscanf()` reads anything and tries to format it as told.

Comment: Thx guys this solved my problem , and I would try changing to fgets cause is true is more optimun for this algorithm =)